# php.exe is not recognized:create webapp

Tags: php, yii, cmd

I am toying with my new install of yii framework, and trying to compile my first webapp through the command line.  when I run `yiic webapp ../testdrive` i receive this error in my console:

```
"php.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Do I need to edit my php.ini file?

I am currently running on WAMP Webserver on Windows 7

Comment: Does your PATH environment variable have the directory that contains `php.exe` in it?

Comment: See http://windows.fyicenter.com/view.php?ID=60

Comment: Thank you guys, I resolved it by adding the php.exe to my Path variables.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add complete path in your `php.exe` in `yii\framework\yiic.bat

for example in my case it is if

`"%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\php.exe`

Comment: How will this differ from how I added php.exe to my PATH environment variables?  Which would be a better method?

Comment: This answer only makes it work for Yii, while your method will make it possible to run php.exe in any command line instance that uses the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @Afnan Bashir Great post here, I have been struggling with this part of Yii on several installs! No more building off of pre-configured sites. They really need to add this to an otherwise bullet proof tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the path of the php.exe before the yiic to execute the php script in windows environment.

your command will look something like this:

> > c:/xampp/php/php.exe path/yiic webapp application_name

Answer (score 0):

when we are creating webapp in yii framework :
Or 
error  ( "php.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file )

php.exe 
file path : C:\xampp\php\php.exe

yiic.bat
File path : C:\xampp\htdocs\YiiMain(foldername)\framework\yiic.bat

"%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND=C:\xampp\php\php.exe

Answer (score 0):

just change the address in `init.bat` file as 
*before*

```
if "%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND=php.exe
```

*after*

```
if "%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe
```

and save it.