# '"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, yii

When I run the command

```
D:\STUDIES\xampp\htdocs\yii\trackstar\protected>yiic migrate create create_project_table
```

in `cmd` it says

```
'"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"
```

Any idea ?

Comment: have you set Path variable?

Comment: Is it in your `PATH` ? [How to add php.exe to your `PATH`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath)

Comment: possible duplicate of [‘php.exe’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464315/php-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php.exe is not recognized:create webapp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706800/php-exe-is-not-recognizedcreate-webapp)

Comment: yes, i have already set the PATH as "D:\STUDIES\xampp\php\php.exe"

Comment: remove last "php.exe"... see my answer below...

Comment: Thank you so much. Removing the last "php.exe" in the path worked. I understood, we just need to give the path :)

Comment: cheers dude... enjoy with Yii

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set environment variable **path** like follow....

```
path :=>...;D:\STUDIES\xampp\php;D:\STUDIES\xampp\yii\yiiframework;
```

or set proper path (based on your dir structure) like above....

Answer (score 0):

You also might need to add ".PHP" to your PATHEXT environment variable.  See http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php