# php.exe is not recognized as an external or internal command

Tags: php, yii

I am trying for create a new project in yii.When I  execute the command `"yiic webapp c:\wamp\www\testyii"` shows the below error

> "php.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command".

My environment variable path is `"%path%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16"`.

How do I solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you run php.exe from command line?

Comment: How did you install PHP? via Wamp/xampp or by itself installer.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781997/php-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progr

And also try the search function.

Comment: before executing this command execute this one: `cd C:\\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16` after that execute your command.

Comment: installed php via wamp

Answer (score 0):

set environment variable path like follow....

```
path =>...;C:\Projects\wamp\php;C:\Projects\wamp\yii\yiiframework;
```

and also include the YII framework path in your path variable

Comment: user is using wamp server not xampp server.

Comment: Yes, Thanks Broken Heart, i just gave the solution overall. Thanks anyways

Comment: Added these C:\Projects\wamp\yii\yiiframework  to variable again run that command  "yiic webapp c:\wamp\www\testyii" shows the error "php.exe is recognized as an internal or external command".

Comment: did you use my variables as is like C:\Projects\wamp\yii\yiiframework t? or replaced / modified according to your path where the framework is set?

Answer (score 0):

change file path, for example :

```
"%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND=E:\xampp\php\php.exe
```