# Could not open input file: yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm working with Yii2 and trying to init some migration files. This was working a few months ago, now I'm getting the following error

```
'yii' is not recognized as an internal or external command

command I'm trying to run is 'yii migrate/create init_my_table
```

I've been looking around but not exactly sure what the problem is.

Seems like this should be a pretty generic and easy to fix error...

Answer (score 20):

Before i delve into proposing a solution, check if you installed Yii's Basic Template or the Advanced Template.

> $ php yii serve

will work for the "basic" template.

Make sure at the Terminal, you have changed to the "basic" directory, then enter the command:

```
 $ php yii serve
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Server started on http://localhost:8080
Document root is "PATH/public_html/yiiproject/basic/web"
Quit the server with CTRL-C or COMMAND-C.
```

IF you are using the Advanced Template, read this thread and see if the Thread here helps. Read it till the very end: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/68728-php-yii-serve/

Had this same issue but was using the Advanced template.

> php yii serve Could not open input file: yii

i tried this command as recommended. It worked:

```
    $ php -S localhost:8000
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE FOR ADVANCED TEMPLATE**

After installing Composer and Yii, open your Advanced template folder in CLI and run this command:

```
  $ php ./init
```

This initialization process will setup the project and create necessary files.

Set your document root properly in apache to your **/advanced/web/**

**More Reading to run your project:**

1. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx/
2. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html

Answer (score 1):

Make you that your Environment Variables are set up correctly.

Check out these links:

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781997/php-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progr)

[Environment Variables](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/)

Relevant parts from links:

> To access the environment variables right click the My Computer icon then choose properties.  Select the Advanced tab and then click Environment Variables.
>
> [window you should see](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/image-thumb20.png)
>
> path :=>...;D:\YOURPATH\xampp\php;D:\YOURPATH\xampp\yii\yiiframework;

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as the link may go stale; could you include the relevant parts in this answer and keep the links as references

Answer (score 0):

Try installing composer globally. I had similar issue but it was resolved after I installed composer via installation file and using my environment variables, I made available globally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).