# sublime text error: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, sublimetext3

Only php path is not enough..........
[Sublime Text3 error:PHP Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt17r.png)

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Search this site for what you wrote as a title, without the *sublime text error*. There are many existing questions (and answers) that provide a solution.

Comment: thanks, but I can't find this in detail!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781997/php-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progr) Strange how I found one in less than 3 minutes.

Comment: thank u
I solved this. It's similar to "http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath"

Answer (score 8):

**To add php & Sublime to the PATH:**
1. Right click Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variable;
2. Under 'System Variables' select variable: Path and hit 'Edit';
3. At the 'Edit environment variable' hit 'New';
4. hit 'Browse';
5. find PHP folder (for me it was "H:\xampp\php") & add (hit 'Ok');
6. Go rule no.3 and no.4 add 'Sublime Text 3'(for me it was "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3")
4. OK, OK, OK

> It's  work also for CMD.
>   Blockquote
>   Thanks

Comment: Your solution is perfect. I am adding one thing. We need to restart sublime to fetch changes.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by disabling the PHP syntax checker plugin in sublimetext. 
CTRL + SHIFT + P >> package control disable package >> php syntax checker.

Answer (score 0):

**Add PHP and Sublime Text to Path under system variables**

Go to properties of Computer(ThisPC/MyComputer) whatever the name is in your case. 
All the steps BAPY has mentioned follow those but for some there might be somthing in the path added already, Just make sure you separate multiple PATHS with a semicolon ;. You are good to go then. It will work.