# Unable to create web app in yii from console

Tags: php, yii

I need to create a skeleton application in yiic from my console. I tried running the following command:

```
yiic webapp demo
```

My yii and frameworks folders are placed here:

```
C:\wamp\www\yii\yii-1.1.14.f0fee9\framework
```

My htdoc folder's path is here:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\htdocs
```

[image]
Can someone guide me here please? Thanks

Comment: You need to specify path to the yiic script or to the demo project directory (according to your current location). For example: `php yiic.php webapp C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\htdocs\demo`

Comment: @Phantom Can you please guide me as per my path settings here. I want to create a skeleton app on the path c:/wamp/www. But still i am getting the same response.

Comment: First: check write permissions for the C:\wamp\www directory. Second: go to the framework directory and execute `yiic webapp C:\wamp\www\demo `

Comment: @Phantom I have unpacked my yii framework inside my c:/wamp/www folder. I am inside the C:\wamp\www\yii\yii-1.1.14.f0fee9\framework folder. I tried running yiic webapp C:\wamp\www\demo from here but still getting the same error. I do have full permissions. What to do exactly?

Comment: @Phantom Here is the error: php.exe is not recognized as an internal or eternal command or batch file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706800/php-exe-is-not-recognizedcreate-webapp

Comment: @Phantom Problem is solved. Thanks a lot for your continuous and valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

The yiic.bat file needs to be edited. We have to provide the full path to our php.exe file placed in the bin folder.